# Parse a string without spaces into an array of individual words

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, parsing

If I have a string "blueberrymuffinsareinsanelydelicious", what is the most efficient way to parse it such that I am left with ["blueberry", "muffins", "are", "insanely", "delicious"]?

I already have my wordlist (mac's /usr/share/dict/words), but how do I ensure that the full word is stored in my array, aka: blueberry, instead of two separate words, blue and berry.

Comment: You could read your words list and then sort it by **word size**, in **reverse order**, before searching the string. In this case, if your words list were `['blue','berry','blueberry']` it would turn out to be `['blueberry','berry','blue']` and your search would look for composite words first.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). How are you getting that list?

Comment: Why is it preferable to parse `blueberry` instead of `blue` and `berry`? Would that also not be a valid solution?

Comment: I'm downvoting the question because it's not clear what is wanted and I don't think any amount of editing would help. It's intrinsically an unanswerable question. How, for example, should the string `"carrotate"` be split up? `["carrot", "ate"]`? `["car", "rotate"]`? `["car", "rot", "ate"]`?. One could easily craft a longer string that has thousands of possible combinations. Questions like this are a waste of everyone's time, including the asker's.

Comment: If, after the string is broken into words found in the dictionary, nothing is to remain in the string, I'm pretty sure this problem is NP-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there's cases where there's multiple interpretations possible and picking the best one can be trouble, you can always approach it with a fairly naïve algorithm like this:

```
WORDS = %w[
  blueberry
  blue
  berry
  fin
  fins
  muffin
  muffins
  are
  insane
  insanely
  in
  delicious
  deli
  us
].sort_by do |word|
  [ -word.length, word ]
end

WORD_REGEXP = Regexp.union(*WORDS)

def best_fit(string)
  string.scan(WORD_REGEXP)
end
```

This will parse your example:

```
best_fit("blueberrymuffinsareinsanelydelicious")
# => ["blueberry", "muffins", "are", "insanely", "delicious"]
```

Note that this skips any non-matching components.

Comment: I'd think it would be smart to keep all possible successful matches from a given start point. You could find yourself in a situation where the longer match of two possible matches is the wrong one, and even the next word doesn't serve to fully disambiguate the result. It might be that it's not until a few steps down the road that the ambiguity is resolved (if at all).

Comment: @DerrellDurrett That's not a bad idea conceptually speaking, but it does complicate the solution considerably.

Comment: LOL. Yup. But it's the only (obvious) way to implement backtracking, so that if you've made a bad choice, you can succeed. Otherwise you'll just end up failing much of the time.

Comment: @DerrellDurrett The regular expression system is surprisingly good at navigating to find the longest, best matches, so it might be a non-issue in all but the most extreme cases.

Comment: That's quite interesting and clever use of regexp. :) But what would happen if the list of words was a big dictionary? Would it grind to a halt, or fail in some other way?

Comment: @phss With any non-trivla regular expression the answer is always "maybe". The larger the list and the larger the data being scanned the higher the probability of a complete melt-down.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It might be better to adapt this to return any unknown chunks as well by spiking in a `.*?` as a catch-all, but I'm not sure about how this will be used.

Comment: For `WORDS #=> ["muffins", "insane", "muffin", "muff", "sane", "in"]` `best_fit "muffinsane" #=> ["muffins"]`, leaves `"ane"` used because that is not an element of `WORDS`, even though `["muffin", "sane"]`, `["muff", "insane"]`, and `["muff", in", "sane"]` all exhaust the string. Is that intended? If you saw my comment on the question you'll see that I'm less than hopeful that anything useful can be done.

Comment: @phss, when I tried using my mac's dictionary (~300,000 words), I got a system level too deep error, but trimming the word list down by half fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive method which finds the correct sentence in 0.4s on my slowish laptop.

- It first imports almost 100K english words and sorts them by decreasing size
- For every `word`, it checks if `text` starts with it
- If it does, it removes the `word` from the `text`, keeps the `word` in an array and recursively calls itself.
- If the `text` is empty, it means a sentence has been found.
- It uses a lazy array to stop at the first found sentence.

---

```
text = "blueberrymuffinsareinsanelydeliciousbecausethey'rereallymoistandcolorful"

dictionary = File.readlines('/usr/share/dict/american-english')
                 .map(&:chomp)
                 .sort_by{ |w| -w.size }

def find_words(text, possible_words, sentence = [])
  return sentence if text.empty?
  possible_words.lazy.select{ |word|
    text.start_with?(word)
  }.map{ |word|
    find_words(text[word.size..-1], possible_words, sentence + [word])
  }.find(&:itself)
end

p find_words(text, dictionary)
#=> ["blueberry", "muffins", "are", "insanely", "delicious", "because", "they're", "really", "moist", "and", "colorful"]
p find_words('someword', %w(no way to find a combination))
#=> nil
p find_words('culdesac', %w(culd no way to find a combination cul de sac))
#=> ["cul", "de", "sac"]
p find_words("carrotate", dictionary)
#=> ["carrot", "ate"]
```

For a faster lookup, it could be a good idea to use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).